# How to connect a Microchip ENC28J60 to 3 port stand alone unmanaged switch chip with out using MCU

Tags: switches, ethernet, port, enc28j60

I have a working design running a Microchip PIC24 with TCP IP stack using the ENC28J60 chip. I am new to switching, and would like to add a second port for daisy chaining multiple devices without having to run ethernet cable back to original source.

I've been looking at all kinds of data sheets trying to understand the networking lingo like a KSZ8794 series chips from Microchip, but can't seem to wrap my head around ( as of now) how to go about having the ENC28J60 chip connect to a switch in unmanaged mode / standalone mode. Then once find a compatible chip, then of course next step would be from the switch to the 2 ports.

Can't seem to find any reference designs, with application notes to understand.

I may be looking too deep, and need a higher level understanding before I can get back deep and choose the proper ethernet switch chip, and reference design.

The ENC28J60 is Fully Compatible with 10/100/1000Base-T Networks and Supports Full and Half-Duplex modes.

Thanks for any links, direction and feedback. Needs to use ethernet cable and not wireless for FYI.

Comment: What specifically is the question? The ethernet connections are same and do not depend on which switch chip is used and whether the switch chip is in standalone or hosted mode. In some cases the ethernet connections can be simplified by omitting the transformers and using capacitive coupling, but not all chips support that, and even more rarely at 10Mbps.

Comment: Having two ethernet ports with a switcher for daisy chaining